# handing the OnCreated event of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I implemented this event of the `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
Private Shared Sub OnCreated(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    If e.Name.ToUpper() == "MYTEXTFILE.TXT" then
        ' code '
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to monitor if created files are in a textbox similar to this?

```
Private Shared Sub OnCreated(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    If e.Name.ToUpper.contains(textbox1.text) then
          ' code '
End Sub
```

Comment: The textbox contains just one file or more than one? And if you have more than one file, how are they separated from each other?

Comment: There are more files,and each is in next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having more than one file in a multiline textbox and every filename is in a separate line requires  that you should split the filenames individually and then check each one with the file just created.

```
Private Shared Sub OnCreated(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    ' Get an array of the files at each line and remove eventually spurious empty lines
    Dim files() = textbox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, _
                                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim newFile = e.Name.ToUpper()
    for each file in files
        if file.ToUpper() = newFile Then
            ' code '
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,i replaced `string newfile = e.name.toupper() ` with `dim newfile as string = e.name.touppper() ` and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have C# in mind at this moment (by the way, it is enough to write `Dim newfile = e.Name.ToUpper()`, the compiler is smart enough to infer that you are working with a string   )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear I understand your question, but I'm assuming that you want to compare the name of the file that was just created with the name of a file in a textbox.

1) Is the text in the textbox also uppercase? I see you uppercase the name of the file before comparing.

2) Is the text in the textbox "containable" in the name of the file, maybe the other way around?

3) Should the condition be .Equal instead of .Contains?

Comment: I used equal and it ain't worked.Text in textbox is lowercase,one on thread was just example.

Comment: And also,I can't use equal because it would compare whole textbox text,contains is the way to go.

Comment: I see you code is in VB, but in C# it wouldn't have compiled because the method ".contains" should've been capitalized. Can that be your issue?

Comment: Nope.I tried everything,so I think I am missing part of code.